# Is there such an integer?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

$\{a_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ and $\{b_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ are two infinite sequences of natural numbers such that for all $n$, $0\leq b_n<a_n$. Is it possible to exist an integer $k$ such that for all $n$, $k\equiv b_n(\mbox{mod } a_n)$?

Thanks for your answer!

Comment: In general, no.

Comment: Yes, it's possible: Let $a_n=2$ for all $n$, and $b_n=1$ for all $n$. Then $b_n=1 ({\rm mod}\> a_n)$ for all $n$.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible if we take $b_n=k$ for all $n$ and $a_n$ to be anything greater than $k$.

Answer (score 2):

Not always possible. To see this, let $k$ be an integer. Then $k$ has the property iff
for every $n \geq 1$ there is an integer $q$ such that
$$k = qa_{n} + b_{n}.$$
If the sequence $(b_{n})$ is not such that $b_{n} =$ const. for all $n \geq 1$ and if $a_{n} = 0$ for all $n \geq 1,$ then there is no $k$ such that $k$ has the property.

Comment: Why there is such a uniform $q$?

Comment: Ah, misread your condition. :) Let me fix this.

Comment: Does not affect the conclusion.

Comment: Why $k$ has this property implies  bn= const. for all n≥1 and an=0 for all n≥1?

Comment: No! I was saying "not always possible" and gave you an example.